# Fijar columnas de tabla html

Tags: jquery, html5, css3, datatables

Lo que quiero hacer es fijar una o varias columnas de una tabla usando css o jquery de manera que no se muevan cuando haga scroll en la tabla, hasta el momento lo que tengo es esto:

```css
table {
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.static {
  position: fixed;
  background: #fff;
}

.first-col {
  padding-left: 74.5px!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered" id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr >
  <th>Fecha</th>
      <th class="static">Concepto</th>
      <th class="first-col">CC</th>
      <th >Last</th>
      <th >Handle</th>
      <th >First</th>
      <th >Last</th>
      <th >Handle</th>
      <th >First</th>
      <th >Last</th>
      <th >Handle</th>
      <th >Handle</th>
      <th >First</th>
      <th >Last</th>
      <th >Handle</th>
      <th >Last</th>
      <th >Handle</th>
      <th >First</th>
      <th >Last</th>
      <th >Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
 <td>03/08/2019</td>
      <td class="static">FIJAR</td>
      <td class="first-col">0</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
 <td>03/08/2019</td>
      <td class="static">FIJAR</td>
      <td class="first-col">0</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
 <td>03/08/2019</td>
      <td class="static">FIJAR</td>
      <td class="first-col">4</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Funciona pero el problema viene cuando es muy grande el texto que esta dentro de la columna que se va a fijar, ya he buscado miles de soluciones y no he podido encontrar algo que de verdad haga lo que estoy pidiendo.

Agradecería que pudieran ayudarme, ya que he estado buscando y no he encontrado soluciones. Ya he visto otras preguntas en este foro pero las soluciones que han dado no me han funcionado como quisiera.

He encontrado una librería llamada fixedColumns y funciona, en este proyecto estoy usando la plantilla adminlte el problema es que esta plantilla usa el archivo adminlte.min.js el cual es obligatorio para que funcione bien la plantilla y al agregar la librería fixedColumns hay cierta incompatibilidad por lo que hace que la tabla se vea mal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.3.0/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.3.0/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
```

**CSS:**

```
th, td { white-space: nowrap; }

tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #ffffff!important;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #c7d1dd!important;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        scrollY:        "300px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false,
        searching:      false,
        bFilter:        false,
        ordering:       false,
        bInfo:          false,
        fixedColumns:   {
            leftColumns: 2
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table" style="width: 100%;" id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Fecha</th>
    <th>Concepto</th>
    <th>CC</th>
    <th>Last</th>
    <th>Handle</th>
    <th>First</th>
    <th>Last</th>
    <th>Handle</th>
    <th>First</th>
    <th>Last</th>
    <th>Handle</th>
    <th>Handle</th>
    <th>First</th>
    <th>Last</th>
    <th>Handle</th>
    <th>Last</th>
    <th>Handle</th>
    <th>First</th>
    <th>Last</th>
    <th>Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>03/08/2019</td>
    <td>FIJAR</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>03/08/2019</td>
    <td>FIJAR</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>03/08/2019</td>
    <td>FIJAR</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Como podría solucionar esta incompatibilidad ya que obligatoria mente necesito la librería fixedColumns para que funcione el posicionamiento fijo de columnas y el archivo adminlte.min.js para que funcione la plantilla AdminLTE??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que encontré después de estar buscando por horas fue lo siguiente:

Yo estaba trabajando con la versión 1.10.16 de JQuery DataTables

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Versión que por alguna razón no trabaja correctamente con la librería **fixedColumns** en su versión 3.3.0 (no se si en versiones anteriores no de problemas) por lo que cambie la versión de JQuery DataTables a 1.10.20 y con esta versión no me esta dando problemas.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```